# what is the 'this' keyword refering to in my code?

Tags: java, this, instance, keyword

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CursorClass implements ActionListener{
        JButton btn;
        JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CursorClass cc = new CursorClass();
        cc.launchButton();
    }

    public void launchButton(){
        frame = new JFrame("Main Window");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        btn = new JButton("Close Main Window");
        btn.setSize(100,100);

        btn.addActionListener(this); // <-------- 

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.add(btn);

        frame.add(pnl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.print("Exiting..");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `launchButton` method.. the `btn.addActionListener(this)` function..

what is the `this`? refering to?

Is it refering to the whole `CursorClass`? 
I'm just a tad bit confused here. I can't understand what I passed to the button object. I know I added the ActionListener to it.. and now the button (which is the event source) will respond to the button when it is clicked but adding `this` in that method.. I'm unable to see what `this` is .. I know that the most common answer is `this` refers to current object, etc.. 
But I need someting more specific.. is my class that I wrote this in considered to be `this`?

Comment: The `instance` of the `btn` at **THE** exact moment.

Comment: Yes. The `this` reference points to the instance owning the surrounding scope. In this case, since your class implements ActionListener, you are providing it as a parameter to the addActionListener method

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance of `CursorClass` which `launchButton` was called on.

Comment: Also, have a look at the typical setTer, where you end with something like `this.x=x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this`, as is being executed in your code, refers exactly to the instance `cc` created there:

```
CursorClass cc = new CursorClass();
```

After that instantiation, you call:

```
cc.launchButton();
```

So, in your example, `this` is `cc`.

The method signature for `addActionListener` is `public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)`, so you have to pass an instance of `ActionListener`, and as you can see in you class definition:

```
public class CursorClass implements ActionListener{
```

CursorClass is a valid class since it implements ActionListener.

What you can see here is the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), where the notification method is the implemented method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){...}`

Comment: By far the BEST explenation . thank you kindly for dumbing it down like that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `CursorClass` implements `ActionListener`. `this` refers to the current instance of `CursorClass`. Essentially, the code adds *itself* ("this" object) as an action listener.

The reason it refers to an instance of `CursorClass` is because it's being called from `launchButton`, which is a method in `CursorClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Object of your class is considered to be `this`.

Lets say you have two objects of CursorClass, A & B.

So, `this` in object A will refer to object A & `this` in object B will refer to object B.

Comment: Also called `self` in some other languages. I think self is more intuitive, maybe it helps to understand the Object metaphor.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding so quick. I will accept the answer later today, I have to go but thank you, that helped.

Comment: @Draconian If you're new to "Object oriented programming", or if you don't know what that is, you should do a search for it and read up about it. (Maybe on Wikipedia). Java is all about OO, so you'll have to get to know it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `this` in java and other Object-Oriented languages is referring to the current class.

So in your case this == `CursorClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that it's referring to the object of this class, or a class that extends this class, that called the method (`launchButton()`).